# [GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with IdentityCredentialError: Error retrieving a token

Tags: google-signin, googlesigninaccount, fedcm

I am testing FedCM since third-party cookie is phasing out.
I've implemented Google OneTap sign-in successfully for years for my website. You can verify it from [live website](https://kontext.tech/).
I am now testing opt-in FebCM. In my browser, this setting is enabled:
`Sites can show sign-in prompts from identity services.`
For third-party cookies, this option is selected: `Block third-party cookies`.

I've added the data attribute accordingly:

```
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="***.apps.googleusercontent.com" 
data-login_uri="https://localhost:50001/account/external-login-google-one-tap?rurl=~%2F" 
data-use_fedcm_for_prompt="true">
</div>
```

When click the prompt sign-in button after page is loaded, I am getting error:
[image: error image]

Error:

```
When fetching the id assertion endpoint, a 403 HTTP response code was received.
localhost/:1 Provider's token is invalid.
client:48 [GSI_LOGGER]: FedCM get() rejects with IdentityCredentialError: Error retrieving a token.
```